# Quartz Scheduler block inactive user job

Tags: c#, .net, scheduler, quartz

I am currently working with Quartz Scheduler and I am trying to make a feature, which will be blocking an user if he is inactive for example for more than two days, but unfortunately I didn't work with Quartz Scheduler and I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Can you define what means "is inactive for example for more than two days," for a user? Do you have a column in your database that holds the latest activity date?

Comment: Yes, I have a column in database that holds the latest activity days. If user is inactive for two or more days the job should block the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well then, you will have a daily cron or an hourly cron (depending on the sensitivity) that checks that value and update the user.

```
public class CheckForInactiveUsers: IJob
{
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        // here you do your business
    }
}


IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<CheckForInactiveUsers>()
    .WithIdentity("checkForInactiveUsers", "group1")
    .Build();

ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
    .StartNow()
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
        .WithIntervalInHours(1)
        .RepeatForever())
    .Build();

await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```